# Submission of form with array of input using AJAX not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Click handler**

```
$('.to-pay').click(function(e)
{
   var finputs=$('form.inputs-form').serialize();
   alert(finputs);
   $.ajax(
   {
       url: "URL_HERE",
       type:"POST",
       data: finputs,
       success: function(data)
       {
      $('.another-div').html(data);
       }
   });
});
```

**PHP part**

```
$pid=$_POST['pid'];
$size=$_POST['product-size'];
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];


foreach($pid as $key => $prod_id)
{
  echo "This part is called";
  echo $prod_id." of size ".$size[$key]." ".$quantity[$key]." numbers.";
}
```

The problem is in the PHP side. The `foreach()` part is not getting executed. In the jQuery side I checked using `alert()` and the data looks like,

**pid%5B%5D=1&product-size%5B%5D=100&quantity%5B%5D=10&pid%5B%5D=2&product-size%5B%5D=150&quantity%5B%5D=20**

What is the problem in the PHP side?

Comment: On the PHP side, what is the output of print_r($_POST); ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: pid in PAGE_URL on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: product-size in PAGE_URL on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: quantity in PAGE_URL on line 4
Array ( [pid] => Array ( [0] => 100000 [1] => 100001 [2] => 100000 ) [quantity] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 ) [product-size] => Array ( [0] => 500 g [1] => 500 g [2] => 1000 g ) ) 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PAGE_URL on line 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
$pid=$_POST['pid'];
$size=$_POST['product-size'];
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];

$i = 0;
foreach($pid as $prod_id)
{
  echo "This part is called";
  echo $prod_id." of size ".$size[$i]." ".$quantity[$i]." numbers.";
$i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dude, 
the alert what you are getting is a string

.serialize()
Description: Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

Solution:
 Use .serializeArray() instead

```
$('form.inputs-form').serializeArray();
```

refer this http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

then at php side change code accordingly.

OR
 At PHP side explode the $_POST['data'], so as to make it a php Array and then iterate the array using foreach

Comment: The alert looks like the proper URL encoding of array parameters. `pid%5B%5D` is the percent-encoding of `pid[]`.

Comment: `serializeArray()` too didn't helped me Sam. Still same issue.

Comment: @SuryaS, according to You 
Notice: Undefined index: pid in PAGE_URL on line 2 Notice: Undefined index: product-size in PAGE_URL on line 3 Notice: Undefined index: quantity in PAGE_URL on line 4

Because you shoule do like this $pid=$_POST['data']['pid'];
$size=$_POST['data']['product-size'];
$quantity=$_POST['data']['quantity'];

As you are passing from jquery with key as data
data: finputs,